# ruby aasm gem: event name change, but permitted method still ask for old event name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aasm

I have been using aasm gem (https://github.com/aasm/aasm) to define an object. It comes with several public method for events. For example:

With object `a_machine`, event `boot_up` would transit the object to a new state `greeting`. I would be able to do the following query: `a_machine.may_boot_up?`. However, I change the name `boot_up` to `wake_up`. Now the following method throws an exception:

```
a_machine.aasm.events(permitted: true)

# undefined method: may_boot_up?
```

I would like to ask how `permitted` is implemented because it still has an outdated public method (associated with an outdated event name).

Other things work fine. Does anyone know why? Or can you please give me further instruction on how to proceed?
Thank you,

EDIT: I have more clue:
After i change the name of the event `:boot_up` to `:wake_up`, what actually happens is that the symbol `:boot_up` still stays in the event array, and a new symbol `:wake_up` is added to that array. `a_machine.aasm.events.map(&:name)` returns the event array.

UPDATE: Now the question is framed as: how to remove an event from AASM::Core::Event because the `:boot_up` was added as an event and by changing the name I accidentally only add a new event `:wake_up`.

Comment: Have you restarted your rails console since you change the state machine?

Comment: LOL @marcbest, do you like putting your comment as an answer so that I mark it solved??? :D took me so much effort to investigate LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to restart your rails console/server once you have made changes to the state machine events.